# What does -f mean with Sort?

Tags: bash, gnu-coreutils

I've been looking over documentation of the Bash system, and I simply have not found an answer to this, that makes sense.

Since notations give different meaning in different contexts - What does the `-f` stand for, in the following command?

```
sort -m -f <(grep "[^A-Z]..$" memo1 | sort) <(grep ".*aba.*" memo2 |sort)
```

I understand the sorting, the merge, the redirection of output and the Grep running regex patterns on memo1 and memo2 respectively.

But what does the `-f` do?

Comment: Since `-f` is an option to `sort`, you should be looking at the documentation for `sort`. Have you done that?

Comment: Yes, and i found the answer of that "It folds lowercase to uppercase", i had to conduct further research on the process of folding to understand what it was refering to with folding. 

I mostly wanted to understand the process, but i figured it out - Thanks!

Comment: It's worth writing your question in such a way as to make it clear that you've read the man page -- otherwise, it looks like a lack of effort. (For instance: "I see in the man page that `-f` 'folds lowercase to uppercase', but what does 'folding' mean in this context?")

Answer (score 2):

```
man sort | grep "\-f"
```

returns :

```
-f, --ignore-case
```

Note that on Ubuntu and derivatives, the LC_COLLATE environment variable is a case-insensitive collation.

It means that `sort` and `sort -f` are equivalent on those platforms when LC_COLLATE isn't changed :

```
echo "B\nA\nb\na\nC" | sort
a
A
b
B
C

echo "B\nA\nb\na\nC" | sort -f
a
A
b
B
C

echo "B\nA\nb\na\nC" |  LC_COLLATE=C sort # <- If you need case sensitive sort.
A
B
C
a
b
```

Comment: What your example shows is that the default `LC_COLLATE` is case-insensitive, not that `sort` is case-insensitive.

Comment: How would you explain the same results for `sort` and `sort -f` otherwise?

Comment: Your `LC_COLLATE` environment variable is a case-insensitive collation. When you change it to `LC_COLLATE=C` you get case-sensitive sorting when you don't use `-f`.